# How to count duplicate rows and compare the two column values in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

This is rows and columns

```
email                mark
A@email.com           50
B@email.com           60
B@email.com           50
B@email.com           60
B@email.com           60
```

This is excepted output

```
email                   mark    totalcount
A@email.com             50      1
B@email.com             50      1
B@email.com             60      3
```

This is my python code

```
df=pd.read_excel('email.xlsx')
df['Total'] = df.mark.apply(lambda x: df.mark.value_counts()[x])
dr = data_file[['email', 'mark', 'totalcount']]
print(dr)
```

my output came like this

```
          email        mark    totalcount
0          A@email.com   50     2
1          B@email.com   60     3
2          B@email.com   50     2
3          B@email.com   60     3
4          B@email.com   60     3
```

how to compare the two-column and add the duplicate row values. so could you please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take both email and mark into account. I think grouping and transforming would work

```py
df['total_count'] = df.groupby(['email', 'mark'])['mark'].transform('count')
dr = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Output:

```py
      email      mark  total_count
0  A@email.com    50            1
1  B@email.com    60            3
2  B@email.com    50            1
```

Comment: or maybe just  `df.groupby(['email', 'mark'],sort=False).size().reset_index(name='total_count')`